# MySql. How to combine several columns in cursor?

Tags: mysql, cursor

I will be very grateful for any help. My situation..
I have a table with students (I write only main columns for this question):

```
| Id | Lastname | Firstname |
_____________________________
| 1  | Smith    | John      |
| 2  | Williams | Robert    |
| 3  | Wilson   | David     |
...
```

A table with works:

```
| Id  | Name    |
_________________
| 1   | Work1   |
| 2   | Work2   |
...
```

A table where write who did this work (number of students who can do the same work can be any)

```
| Id | WorkId | StudentId |
___________________________
| 1  | 1      | 1         |
| 2  | 1      | 2         |
| 3  | 2      | 1         |
| 4  | 2      | 2         |
| 5  | 2      | 3         |
...
```

And I need to make a table in procedure (**with using cursor**) like this:

```
| WorkName     | Students                           |
_____________________________________________________
| Work1        | (Smith J., Williams R.)            |
| Work2        | (Smith J., Williams R., Wilson D.) |
...
```

I don't understand completely how to use cursor in this case. My code:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE Report()
BEGIN    
DECLARE students VARCHAR(200);  
DECLARE id_s INT;
  
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;

DECLARE get_cur CURSOR FOR 
SELECT Id, CONCAT(Lastname, ' ', LEFT(Firstname,1), '. ') FROM students;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

open get_cur;
read_loop: LOOP

FETCH get_cur INTO id_s, students;  

IF done THEN
LEAVE read_loop;
END IF;

SELECT w.Name, students
 FROM Work w
JOIN WorkStudent ws ON w.Id=ws.WorkId
JOIN Students s ON s.Id = ws.StudentId 
WHERE s.Id=id_s;

END LOOP;

CLOSE get_cur;  

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: It can easily be done with `group_concat`. No cursors needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem. For this decision I create a new table and I insert new row in this table if the student is not yet now in this table, and update this table (set new student and comma) if the student is present in table. And I did this with via cursors.
This is the final right decision. Now everything works.